# Is it possible to use github:gist with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, code, embed

I have a wordpress blog i.e. bruno.wordpress.com
I would like to use [github:gist](https://gist.github.com/).

I paste my code in gist and get a link like: https://gist.github.com/1323748

Is there a way to show this code in my blog? (rather than just a link to the code.)

Comment: Questions regarding WordPress.com and its features are explicitly off-topic according to our [site's FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

As scribu mentions, you can do this on a self-hosted WordPress site with a plugin.  In WordPress.com, though, you don't have access to these plugins and must depend on the oEmbed support WordPress.com extends you by default.

Your best bet is to contact their support team directly and ask if/when they'll have support for Gist via oEmbed.

Comment: Please edit your answer.. It is now possible as mentioned below by jrochkind.

Answer (score 4):

It may not have been possible in Oct 2011, but it is now. hosted wordpress.com automatically recognizes gist URLs and will embed them.

http://en.support.wordpress.com/gist/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, using the [oEmbed Gist](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oembed-gist/) plugin.

Comment: I don't have a local copy of wordpress. I signed up for a free wordpress blog. \

Comment: another quite popular plugin seems to be http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/embed-github-gist/